# Why isn't Spring injecting a map into a child Struts 2 Action class but parent's objects are injected?

Tags: java, spring, struts2, ioc-container

I have the following configuration in my Spring applicationContext.xml in order to inject objects into my Struts 2 Java project:

```
<util:map id="typeToURLMap">
    <entry key="TYPEA" value="./ur1.x" />
    <entry key="TYPEB" value="./url2.x" />
    <entry key="TYPEC" value="./url3.x" />
    <entry key="OTHER" value="./url4.x" />
</util:map>

<bean id="parentAction" class="my.package.ParentAction" scope="prototype">
    <property name="businessDelegate" ref="businessDelegateNotRelevantToThisExample" />
</bean>

<bean id="childAction" class="my.package.ChildAction" scope="prototype" parent="parentAction">
    <property name="typeToURLMap" ref="typeToURLMap"/>
</bean>
```

For some reason, the setter is being called on the parent Action, but not in the child Action.  **Is there anything wrong with this configuration?**

Note:  It is my understanding that util:map will default to a Java type of HashMap.

**My ParentAction looks like the following:**

```
 public class ParentAction extends MyAppBaseAction {

        private BusinessDelegate businessDelegate;

        //other action code using business delegate

        /**
         *  This IS called.
        */
        public void setBusinessDelegate(BusinessDelegate delegate){
            this.businessDelegate = delegate;
        }
    }
```

**My ChildAction looks like the following:**

```
public class ChildAction extends ParentAction{

    private Map<String,String> typeToURLMap;

    //other action code using map

    /**
     *  Never Called! (Why?)
    */
    public void setTypeToURLMap(Map<String,String map){
        this.typeToURLMap = map;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: does it give an "cannot set property" exception or does it just silently fail?

Comment: It silently fails.  I haven't see any exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a unit test for the applicationContext.xml file

```
public class ApplicationContextTest extends TestCase {

  protected ApplicationContext      ctx;

  protected static final String[]   CONTEXT_LOCATIONS = new String[] {
      "classpath:resources/applicationContext.xml"};

  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONTEXT_LOCATIONS);
  }

  public void test() {
    ChildAction ca = ctx.getBean("childAction", ChildAction.class);
    assertNotNull(ca.getTypeToURLMap());
  }
}
```

If the test passes then look at how struts is integrated with spring

Comment: This test fails because the injecting setter method is never fired.  My struts configuration instantiates the ChildAction and calls the correct methods.  The real problem is that the injected map object is still null when it comes time to use it, and throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: can you tell me what version of spring you are using, please?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, it is Spring v2.5.  I am including the following utils library..  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd

Comment: Liviu, you were right to suggest taking a look at my Struts configuration.  The struts.xml was using a fully-qualified class name instead of the Spring bean reference, so it was never picked up.  I am still a little confused why the parent class's business delegate was still called, though.  I have found the solution.  Thanks.